# Google Chrome. Some sites are not working

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

In my Google Chrome some websites are opening and some are not. For ex. Codechef.com is opening but youtube.com gmail.com is not opening. Why this is happening and what I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: if you open the terminal and use the command `nslookup` for each site you are testing in Chrome, do you get errors for gmail and youtube?  `nslookup youtube.com`

Comment: It is showing  Server:127.0.0.53    Address: 127.0.0.53#53 Non-authoritative answer:   Name : youtube.com Address:172.217.167.238   Name:youtube.com Address: 2404:6800:4002:80f::200e

Comment: are you behind a proxy or firewall?  The nslookup worked fine.